How to draw on an image file
I have a Uint8List object which represents a picture. Then, I call a method that analyzes the picture and if some faces are present, it gives back a list of coordinates. At this point, I have to edit the original Uint8List file and draw one or more square in the picture on the coordinates I received.
How can I accomplish this last part? I just need a method that takes the file, elaborates it and save it, without showing the user the result

convert it to ui.Image and use Canvas API to draw rectangles

and you can do that with decodeImageFromList function which takes Uint8List as a parameter

I'm not sure whether you are able to edit Uint8List.
But you can wrap it with Stack and draw whatever you want above the image.
I mean you will know an image size and coordinates.

yes this is exactly what I am doing at the moment, but I would like to have a method that changes the image itself, without having to use Stack
